# Does the following concept regarding measure hold good?

Tags: measure-theory

If $A$ and $B$ be two disjoint sets then $m^* (A \cup B) = m^* (A) + m^* (B)$, where $m^* (X)$ denotes the outer measure of $X$.

Is it true?If 'yes' then please help me to proceed.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not true.  You need to assume $A,B$ are measurable.  Indeed this is practically the entire point of the concept of measurable sets.

Comment: What is the counter-example to disprove it?

Comment: Let $A$ be a Vitali set in $[0,1]$ and $B = [0,1] \setminus A$.

Comment: It is true, however, if $A,B\subset \mathbb{R}^n, m$ is the Lebesgue measure and $d(A,B) > 0$ (regardless of measurability).